# google page rank get in python

Tags: python, seo

I need google page rank get in python. There i can officially extract it? i mean i can parse some thing like this http://www.prchecker.info
But there these sites get data officially from google? or may i can use some python seo libs for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I posted about getting PageRank here:
http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2010/01/python-lookup-google-pagerank-score.html

the code you need is here:
http://code.google.com/p/corey-projects/source/browse/trunk/python2/pagerank.py

it uses the Google Toolbar 3.0.x/4.0.x Pagerank Checksum Algorithm.

(note:  this might not give you the rank they use internally for results, but it will give you whatever pagerank that the Google toolbar would display for the given page)

Answer (score 8):

I needed to recently do the same thing and couldn't find any examples of working python code to get the google page rank via their toolbar API. I did find an example written in perl on CPAN (WWW:Google:PageRank) and I reimplemented it in python. I also have a class for getting the Alexa traffic rank from their toolbar.

https://github.com/aablack/websearchapp/blob/master/search/rank_provider.py

I know the question is old but I'm hoping it may be of use to other people searching for solutions to this problem.

Comment: @mrpringle, Can I run the same code for a list of urls (a text file?)

Comment: I don't see why not, given you add the code to read from the text file of course:)

Answer (score -4):

No, there is no official PageRank API. There are various hacks, which you can google.